How to compile Swift with Scons?
I am trying to create an iOS plugin for Godot Game Engine. For that I need to create a static library. I am trying to call my swift code from objective-c++. Here is the source code
I am trying to call my swift code from arithematic.mm
I have created the Bridging Header for my swift file and included it in arithematic.mm
#import "arithematic-Swift.h"

Now Godot requires scons to build the '.a' file from a static library, to do that we need to run scons target=release_debug arch=arm64 plugin=arithematic version=4.0 but as soon as I run it I get error saying
arithematic/arithematic.mm:10:9:{10:9-10:30}: fatal error: 'arithematic-Swift.h' file not found [1]
 #import "arithematic-Swift.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
scons: *** [arithematic/arithematic.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors. 

Now I also have a SConstruct file which I am guessing is causing the issue
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import subprocess

if sys.version_info < (3,):
    def decode_utf8(x):
        return x
else:
    import codecs
    def decode_utf8(x):
        return codecs.utf_8_decode(x)[0]

# Most of the settings are taken from https://github.com/BastiaanOlij/gdnative_cpp_example

opts = Variables([], ARGUMENTS)

# Gets the standard flags CC, CCX, etc.
env = DefaultEnvironment()

# Define our options
opts.Add(EnumVariable('target', "Compilation target", 'debug', ['debug', 'release', "release_debug"]))
opts.Add(EnumVariable('arch', "Compilation Architecture", '', ['', 'arm64', 'armv7', 'x86_64']))
opts.Add(BoolVariable('simulator', "Compilation platform", 'no'))
opts.Add(BoolVariable('use_llvm', "Use the LLVM / Clang compiler", 'no'))
opts.Add(PathVariable('target_path', 'The path where the lib is installed.', 'bin/'))
opts.Add(EnumVariable('plugin', 'Plugin to build', '', ['', 'arithematic']))
opts.Add(EnumVariable('version', 'Godot version to target', '', ['', '3.x', '4.0']))


# Updates the environment with the option variables.
opts.Update(env)

# Process some arguments
if env['use_llvm']:
    env['CC'] = 'clang'
    env['CXX'] = 'clang++'

if env['arch'] == '':
    print("No valid arch selected.")
    quit();

if env['plugin'] == '':
    print("No valid plugin selected.")
    quit();

if env['version'] == '':
    print("No valid Godot version selected.")
    quit();

# For the reference:
# - CCFLAGS are compilation flags shared between C and C++
# - CFLAGS are for C-specific compilation flags
# - CXXFLAGS are for C++-specific compilation flags
# - CPPFLAGS are for pre-processor flags
# - CPPDEFINES are for pre-processor defines
# - LINKFLAGS are for linking flags

# Enable Obj-C modules
env.Append(CCFLAGS=["-fmodules", "-fcxx-modules"])

if env['simulator']:
    sdk_name = 'iphonesimulator'
    env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-mios-simulator-version-min=16.0'])
    env.Append(LINKFLAGS=["-mios-simulator-version-min=16.0"])
else:
    sdk_name = 'iphoneos'
    env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-miphoneos-version-min=16.0'])
    env.Append(LINKFLAGS=["-miphoneos-version-min=16.0"])

try:
    sdk_path = decode_utf8(subprocess.check_output(['xcrun', '--sdk', sdk_name, '--show-sdk-path']).strip())
except (subprocess.CalledProcessError, OSError):
    raise ValueError("Failed to find SDK path while running xcrun --sdk {} --show-sdk-path.".format(sdk_name))

env.Append(CCFLAGS=[
    '-fobjc-arc', 
    '-fmessage-length=0', '-fno-strict-aliasing', '-fdiagnostics-print-source-range-info', 
    '-fdiagnostics-show-category=id', '-fdiagnostics-parseable-fixits', '-fpascal-strings', 
    '-fblocks', '-fvisibility=hidden', '-MMD', '-MT', 'dependencies', '-fno-exceptions', 
    '-Wno-ambiguous-macro', 
    '-Wall', '-Werror=return-type',
    # '-Wextra',
])

env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-arch', env['arch'], "-isysroot", "$IOS_SDK_PATH", "-stdlib=libc++", '-isysroot', sdk_path])
env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-DPTRCALL_ENABLED'])
env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=[
    '-DNEED_LONG_INT', '-DLIBYUV_DISABLE_NEON', 
    '-DIOS_ENABLED', '-DUNIX_ENABLED', '-DCOREAUDIO_ENABLED'
])
env.Append(LINKFLAGS=["-arch", env['arch'], '-isysroot', sdk_path, '-F' + sdk_path])

if env['arch'] == 'armv7':
    env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=['-fno-aligned-allocation'])

if env['version'] == '3.x':
    env.Append(CCFLAGS=["$IPHONESDK"])
    env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=['-DIPHONE_ENABLED'])
    env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=['-DVERSION_3_X'])

    env.Prepend(CFLAGS=['-std=gnu11'])
    env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=['-DGLES_ENABLED', '-std=gnu++14'])

    if env['target'] == 'debug':
        env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=[
            '-gdwarf-2', '-O0', 
            '-DDEBUG_MEMORY_ALLOC', '-DDISABLE_FORCED_INLINE', 
            '-D_DEBUG', '-DDEBUG=1', '-DDEBUG_ENABLED',
            '-DPTRCALL_ENABLED',
        ])
    elif env['target'] == 'release_debug':
        env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=['-O2', '-ftree-vectorize',
            '-DNDEBUG', '-DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1', '-DDEBUG_ENABLED', 
            '-DPTRCALL_ENABLED',
        ])

        if env['arch'] != 'armv7':
            env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=['-fomit-frame-pointer'])
    else:
        env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=[
            '-O2', '-ftree-vectorize',
            '-DNDEBUG', '-DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1', 
            '-DPTRCALL_ENABLED',
        ])

        if env['arch'] != 'armv7':
            env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=['-fomit-frame-pointer'])
elif env['version'] == '4.0':
    env.Append(CCFLAGS=["$IOS_SDK_PATH"])
    env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=['-DIOS_ENABLED'])
    env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=['-DVERSION_4_0'])

    env.Prepend(CFLAGS=['-std=gnu11'])
    env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=['-DVULKAN_ENABLED', '-std=gnu++17'])

    if env['target'] == 'debug':
        env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=[
            '-gdwarf-2', '-O0', 
            '-DDEBUG_MEMORY_ALLOC', '-DDISABLE_FORCED_INLINE', 
            '-D_DEBUG', '-DDEBUG=1', '-DDEBUG_ENABLED', 
        ])
    elif env['target'] == 'release_debug':
        env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=[
            '-O2', '-ftree-vectorize',
            '-DNDEBUG', '-DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1', '-DDEBUG_ENABLED',
        ])

        if env['arch'] != 'armv7':
            env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=['-fomit-frame-pointer'])
    else:
        env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=[
            '-O2', '-ftree-vectorize',
            '-DNDEBUG', '-DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1',
        ])

        if env['arch'] != 'armv7':
            env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=['-fomit-frame-pointer'])            
else:
    print("No valid version to set flags for.")
    quit();

# Adding header files
if env['version'] == '3.x':
    env.Append(CPPPATH=[
        '.', 
        'godot', 
        'godot/platform/iphone',
    ])
else:
       env.Append(CPPPATH=[
        '.', 
        'godot', 
        'godot/platform/ios',
    ])

# tweak this if you want to use different folders, or more folders, to store your source code in.
# sources = Glob('plugin/' + env['plugin'] + '/*.mm')
# sources.append(Glob('plugin/' + env['plugin'] + '/*.mm'))
# sources.append(Glob('plugin/' + env['plugin'] + '/*.m'))


sources = Glob('arithematic/*.cpp')
sources.append(Glob('arithematic/*.mm'))
sources.append(Glob('arithematic/*.m'))



# lib<plugin>.<arch>-<simulator|ios>.<release|debug|release_debug>.a
# library_platform = env["arch"] + "-" + ("simulator" if env["simulator"] else ("iphone" if env['version'] == '3.x' else "ios"))
# library_name = env['plugin'] + "." + library_platform + "." + env["target"] + ".a"
# library = env.StaticLibrary(target=env['target_path'] + library_name, source=sources)

library_platform = env["arch"] + "-" + ("simulator" if env["simulator"] else "iphone")
library_name = env['plugin'] + "." + library_platform + "." + env["target"] + ".a"
library = env.StaticLibrary(target=env['target_path'] + library_name, source=sources)

Default(library)

# Generates help for the -h scons option.
Help(opts.GenerateHelpText(env))

As you can see above it does not know how to compile the Bridging-Header and swift file
Here is what I tried adding in the above SConstruct file
# Adding header files
if env['version'] == '3.x':
    env.Append(CPPPATH=['.', 'godot', 'godot/platform/iphone', ])
else:
    env.Append(CPPPATH=['.', 'godot', 'godot/platform/ios', ])

# ...

sources = Glob('arithematic/*.cpp')
sources.append(Glob('arithematic/*.h'))
sources.append(Glob('arithematic/*.mm'))
sources.append(Glob('arithematic/*.m'))
sources.append(Glob('arithematic/*.swift'))

# ...

env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-swiftc', '-import-objc-header', 'arithematic-Swift.h'])
env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['-swiftc', '-import-objc-header', 'arithematic-Swift.h'])
env['SWIFTCOM'] = 'swiftc'

# ...

It results in even more errors as I don't have enough experience in scons

SCons doesn't currently know how to scan swift for dependencies.

SCons itself doesn't know anything at all about Swift (it does, however, at least minimally understand about Objective C and C++) - but Godot does. The error above smells like a path problem - doesn't look like the message is from SCons, beyond it just passing through something the compiler is reporting.  I'd look at whether CPPPATH needs something added to it to locate the header. Barring that - wait for a Godot + Swift expert to pop in - maybe also ask on the Godot forum to cover your bases.

@bdbaddog Thanks for the reply, when I try to build it using Xcode it works but as soon as I run scons target=release_debug arch=arm64 plugin=arithematic version=4.0 I started getting error

@MatsWichmann Yeah I will try the Godot forums. Do you know where to look for CPPPATH  in Xcode. I tried Build settings in Xcode and can't find anything related to path

@MatsWichmann Ok I understood what you mean, I tried adding this path /Users/Desktop/samples/Godot/mytrial/work/plugin/arithematic to CPPPATH in SConstruct but same issue. Also tried /Users/Desktop/samples/Godot/mytrial/work/plugin/arithematic/arithematic-Swift.h and /Users/Desktop/samples/Godot/mytrial/work/plugin/arithematic/arithematic-Bridging-Header.h
